# How to start process in linux C++

Tags: c++, linux, process

I tried to use exec() function, but i need function for unix/linux, which can start process with:

1. Working directory
2. Arguements
3. Important! enviroment variables, like LD_PRELOAD

Thanks!

Comment: He needs `fork()` , `chdir()`, `setenv()` and `exec()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you fork() you get a duplicate of the current process (So the same working directory), and then you can exec with the parameters you need, this replaces the current program text (code) with what's in the target executable. Try 'man exec' for usage or google 'fork exec' for an example.

eg.

```
if (fork() == 0) {
  // Child process
  exec("./test", "./test", "-a", NULL); // check the null though
}
// Parent process
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the execle or execvpe to launch your command with the arguments and override the environment variables (see man execvpe). For example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv[]) {
    char * const environment[] = {"TOTO=Hello world", NULL};
    char * const args[] = {"bash", "-c", "pwd; echo ""TOTO is $TOTO""", NULL};
    chdir("/");
    execvpe("bash", args, environment);
}
```

Outputs

```
/
TOTO is Hello world
```